# how to trigger a action on power automate when any page created on modified in azure devops wiki

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, powerapps, power-automate-custom-connector

I am trying to create a chat bot where the data source is azure wiki and share point, where  I collect the documents and send it to storage account, I was able to do this using the connectors provided by Power automate triggers for SharePoint on file creation.

Now I am trying to do this azure wiki(not pushed through programmatically), my requirement is whenever there is new page creation or page modification through UI, a trigger action has to be performed.

For alternative I checked the documentation of Microsoft for service hooks, based on the document I do not see any action related to wiki. I also tried adding the repository and using the trigger "when code is pushed" and that is not triggering in power automate.

[image]

Could anyone help, what alternatives I can try ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of wiki are you using? Project wiki or code wiki? You can try to use code wiki and check if it can work